# Crashlytics.getInstance() returns null for logging custom exceptions

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, google-fabric

I am trying to log caught exceptions as recommended in the [doc](https://docs.fabric.io/javadocs/crashlytics/2.6.4/com/crashlytics/android/Crashlytics.html)

In one of my Activity:

```
@Override
public void failure(RetrofitError error) {                                              
    Crashlytics.getInstance().core.log(error.getMessage());
    Crashlytics.getInstance().core.logException(error.getCause());
}
```

But this again results in a fatal exception in Fabric dashboard:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   Attempt to read from field 'com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.core' on a null object reference

I am initializing Fabric in `AndroidApplication`:

```
CrashlyticsCore core = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build();
Fabric.with(this, new Answers(), new Beta(), core, new TwitterCore(authConfig), new Digits.Builder().build());
```

Do I need to initialize Fabric for each activity on which I require custom logging?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Initializing Fabric in the onCreate should be all you need to do. Are you logging any of those logs in Retrofit Error before Fabric has been fully initialized?

Comment: @MikeBonnell No this happens very well after application is initialized

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar setup in my app. I initialize Crashlytics like so:

```
Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder()
            .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build())
            .build();

    Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit);
```

However I'm just using the Crashlytics log method like so:

```
if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Crashlytics.log(message);
}
```

Comment: My errors are from production, so `!BuildConfig.DEBUG` check won't solve the issue. `Crashlytics.getInstance()` would still return null

Comment: Not sure why then if your Application subclass is registered in the manifest file why it would be null. If you just use the Crashlytics.log(message) method does it still crash?